# Uncaught ReferenceError: Buffer is not defined. Using Phantom Wallet, Solana and React to make a transaction

Tags: transactions, testing, react, buffer

I've created a simple app to figure out how to use a Phantom wallet to make Solana transactions. I'm trying to follow SolDev course: https://soldev.app/course/interact-with-wallets.
When I test the app and I press the button to send Solana to another account I got the following error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: Buffer is not defined`

[image]

This is my Code:

```
const sendSol = event => {
    event.preventDefault()

    const transaction = new Web3.Transaction()
    const to = Web3.Keypair.generate();

    const sendSolInstruction = Web3.SystemProgram.transfer({
        fromPubkey: publicKey,
        toPubkey: to.publicKey,
        lamports: LAMPORTS_PER_SOL * 0.1
    })

    transaction.add(sendSolInstruction);
    sendTransaction(transaction, connection).then(sig => {
        console.log(sig)
    })
}
```

I got the error in the line `toPubkey: to.publicKey,`

Aditional info: I got this warning in the console:

```
WARNING in ./node_modules/@solana/buffer-layout/lib/Layout.js
Module Warning (from ./node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Failed to parse source map from 'D:\Solana\SolanaCourse\solanacourse1\node_modules\@solana\buffer-layout\src\Layout.ts' file: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\Solana\SolanaCourse\solanacourse1\node_modules\@solana\buffer-layout\src\Layout.ts'
```

[image]

Hope somebody could help me. If you need extra information please tell me.
Thanks!

Comment: Are you using webpack 5 perchance?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is happening because the default bundler that comes with create react app(webpack 5) does not polyfill `Buffer`. The easiest way to fix this is including this code in your app:

```
import * as buffer from "buffer";
window.Buffer = buffer.Buffer;
```

Comment: I try this in a new project without all my settings and can confirm this fix also works for me. Thanks Acheron!

Comment: Thanks this works for me. I was stuck in solana/web3.js buffer error on a reactjs app.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for trying to help me.
I managed to get my code working finally. I've to do a couple of things I want to share:

FIRST: Make sure you've all these dev dependencies installed

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.3.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "@types/jest": "^28.1.5",
    "@types/node": "^18.0.4",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.15",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.6",
    "process": "^0.11.10",
    "react-app-rewired": "^2.2.1",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "source-map-loader": "^4.0.0",
    "typescript": "^4.7.4"
  }
```

SECOND: Make this change in package.json => "scripts"

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-app-rewired start",
    "build": "react-app-rewired build",
    "test": "react-app-rewired test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
```

THIRD: Create a new file in your project root named "config-overrides.js" with this code in it

```
const { ProvidePlugin } = require('webpack');

module.exports = function (config, env) {
    return {
        ...config,
        module: {
            ...config.module,
            rules: [
                ...config.module.rules,
                {
                    test: /.(m?js|ts|tsx)$/,
                    enforce: 'pre',
                    use: ['source-map-loader'],
                },
            ],
        },
        plugins: [
            ...config.plugins,
            new ProvidePlugin({
                process: 'process/browser',
            }),
        ],
        resolve: {
            ...config.resolve,
            fallback: {
                assert: require.resolve('assert'),
                buffer: require.resolve('buffer'),
            },
        },
        ignoreWarnings: [/Failed to parse source map/],
    };
};
```

FOURTH: Create a file in your project root named "tsconfig.js" with this code in it

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
        "allowJs": true,
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "strict": true,
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
        "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
        "module": "esnext",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
        "isolatedModules": true,
        "noEmit": true,
        "jsx": "react-jsx"
    },
    "include": ["src"]
}
```

And that's all. I'm not sure if all steps and all dependencies are necessary to solve the issue. I pick a working project from a friend and set mine to have the same settings.

What I could say for sure is that before the THIRD step my code was still not working.

Thanks to people that try to help me. In a new project I will try acheron solution, maybe all my steps are not really needed.

Good luck to all!

Answer (score 1):

if you are using Sveltekit after importing the  import { Buffer } from 'buffer'; you need to load it in the browser by importing
import { browser } from '$app/environment';

if(browser){
window.Buffer = Buffer;
}

Answer (score 0):

I was using the @solana/web3.js library, client-side version. I got this error suddenly, without any changes to code that was working previously. What worked for me was to use an older version of @solana/web3.js

Answer (score 0):

That is webpack5 issue. Because to reduce the size of package webpack5 removed polyfills and you have to manually install them. Easy way to set up is, first install:

```
npm i node-polyfill-webpack-plugin
```

Then in your webpack.config.js

```
const NodePolyfillPlugin = require("node-polyfill-webpack-plugin");

plugins: [
    ....
    new NodePolyfillPlugin(),
   ]
```

you can fork this repo [webpack5-Boilerplate](https://github.com/yilmazbingo/webpack5-Boilerplate)